# Edit I-search word in emacs?

Tags: search, emacs

When I search in the text, I type C-s, then type the word, then type C-s again and again, the cursor go forward to next locations of found words. The problem is, once I go to next word, I could not edit the search word in the mini buffer at the button, if I press Backspace, it goes to the previous found word in the text, but not deleting the last letter in the search word at the bottom. How can I get back to edit the word when doing the search?

Comment: `C-s C-h C-h` for isearch help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `M-e` at any time during Isearch to edit the search string.  When done editing, just resume searching (e.g., with `C-s`).

Answer (score 5):

I never liked the default behavior of backspace in isearch, so I made it delete the last character of the search string:

```
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "<backspace>") 'isearch-del-char)
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you press backspace as many times as you pressed C-s, it will start removing the characters.